# Only print if the number of field is greater than a value with awk

Tags: awk

I'm still a newbie to awk, what am I doing wrong?
apologies for the poor description, I reformulate.

**Goal**

Only print the number of the second field if the number is > 20

```
lorem v3  <--- no print
ipsum v5  <--- no print
text v21  <--- print "21"
expla v12 <--- no print
```

**My attempt that does not work**

```
awk ' { sub("^v","",$2); if ( $2 > 20 ) print $2 } '
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addressing OP's question about why the current code outputs `3`:

Initially `awk` doesn't know if `$2` is a number or a string.

The `sub()` call (a string function) tells `awk` that `$2` is to be treated as a string, which also means `$2` will be treated as a string for the rest of the script.

This leads to `$2 > 20` being treated as a string comparison (`'3' > '20'`) and since `'3'` (the string) is 'greater than' `'20'` (the string), a `3` is output.

To facilitate a numeric comparion we need a way to force `awk` to re-evaluate `$2` as a numeric. One method is to add a zero, ie, `$2+0`.  Making this one change to OP's current code:

```
$ echo "lorem v3" | awk ' { sub("^v","",$2); if ( $2+0 > 20 ) print $2 } '
           <<< no output
```

**NOTE:** for more details see [GNU awk - variable typing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Typing.html)

---

Addressing the latest change to the question:

Sample input:

```
$ cat input.dat
lorem v3
ipsum v5
text v21
expla v12
```

Running our `awk` code (additional `print` added for clarification) against `input.dat`:

```
$ awk ' { print "######",$0; sub("^v","",$2); if ( $2+0 > 20 ) print $2 } ' input.dat
###### lorem v3
###### ipsum v5
###### text v21
21
###### expla v12
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. Simple explanation would be, printing values by `echo` command of shell and sending its output as standard input to `awk` program. In `awk` program checking condition using `sub`(substitute) function to substitute everything apart from digits in 2nd field with NULL AND checking if $2+0 is greater than 20, if both condition are met then print that line's 2nd field.

```
echo "lorem v3" | awk 'sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$2) && $2+0>20{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could check if the format of the second field is `v` followed by digits greater than 20, and when printing remove the first character.

The pattern for the digits matches 21-29 or 30-99 or 100 and above.

```
awk '
match($2, /^v(2[1-9]|[3-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})$/){
  print substr($2,2);
}' file
```

Output

```
21
```