# How to count the number of row in multiple files based on condition in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, command

I'm trying to count row based on condition through multiple files then summary.Condition is value greater than 60.

```
> sample1.txt

name  value
A001     27
A002     54
A003     39
A004     81
A005     88


> sample2.txt

name  value
B001     46
B002     92
B003     79
B004     67
B005     66

> sample3.txt

name  value
C001     12
C002     39
C003     83
C004     79
C005     27
```

Desired output:

```
   file  Count
sample1      2
sample2      4
sample3      2
```

I have tried :

```
awk '$2>60{c++} END{print c+0}' sample1.txt
```

but this code will count header also, and I'm stucking at how to summary all files.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72087314/only-print-if-the-number-of-field-is-greater-than-a-value-with-awk) answer your question?

Comment: @Uberhumus this question help for the header problem, but does not clarify how to do a summary of all files

Comment: Try `awk 'NR > 1 && $2>60{c++} END{print c+0}' sample1.txt`

Comment: yes.it's solve header problem but I can't get result of summary.

Comment: Try `cat sample1.txt sample2.txt sample3.txt | awk 'NR > 1 && $2>60{c++} END{print c+0}'`?

Comment: @Alegría, does catting all of the files to the `awk` resolve the summary issue?

Comment: @Uberhumus using cat and pipping won't work. First, `awk` will consider the input as one file (try `{print NR, FNR}`), this will make it really hard to summarize the output. Second, as `awk` consider the input as one file `NR>1` will only work on the first line, that will make the counter increment for each header other than the first one (at least for gawk 5.1.1).

Comment: @Uberhumus,sorry for the late reply.It's not work. I got  ```10``` only, without file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially `awk` doesn't know if $2 is a number or a string.

After that you only have one counter `c`, this will lead to having only one count at the end of your script.
To avoid that you can use an array using the `FILENAME` as index to count every value of each file.

script.awk :

```
!(FILENAME in a){a[FILENAME]=0} 
$2+0>60{a[FILENAME]++} 
END{
    print "file", "count"
    for(key in a) print key, a[key]
}
```

The line `!(FILENAME in a){a[FILENAME]=0}`  is useful if you have a file that never match your condition, as otherwise these would not show up in the summary

If you need a total you can add a counter in the first part of the script or in the `for` loop at the end. In these examples below `c` will equal.

```
!(FILENAME in a){a[FILENAME]=0}
$2+0>60{a[FILENAME]++} 
END{
    print "file", "count"
    for(key in a){
        print key, a[key]
        c+=a[key]
    }
    print "total", c
}
```

or

```
!(FILENAME in a){a[FILENAME]=0}
$2+0>60{a[FILENAME]++; c++} 
END{
    print "file", "count"
    for(key in a) print key, a[key]
    print "total", c
}
```

You can use these as script :

```
awk -f script.awk sample1.txt sample2.txt sample3.txt
```